# Simple gui to launch a powershell script and pass parameters

Tags: wpf, user-interface, powershell

I have a Powershell V2 script that is done and all dandy. I pass parameters to it via

`myscript.ps1 -firstparameter Donald -secondparameter Duck`

I would like to have a "kicker" or "launcher" window/gui that simply lets me pass the arguments. I've designed the GUI in PrimalForms but I can't figure out how to send the arguments to my script and launch it.

**My questions are:**

- How would I start my script with my parameters from my PrimalForms GUI (or any other gui)?
- Am I even on the right track here (having my script as a separate scriptfile) or shold I try to put my entire script inside the PrimalForms project?
- Is PrimalForms the way to go with a task like this? (I've been hearing about WPF and I'm thinking with the upcoming release of PS3 and all..)

PS: As of now I do not need any interaction with the GUI after "OK" have been pressed. I have no problem seeing a Powershell window pop up and do all the work in its "ugly glory"..

All help/tips are GREATLY appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in PrimalForms i'm imagining you create a few user input controls (textboxes, etc) and you have a button to click to launch your script with the parameters the user entered into your form input controls. If this is the case you would create an event handler for the button and add the code to call your script to the script block handler. If you are using the free community edition, on the right you will see at the top of the properties pane a lightning bolt icon. This will add the code templates linking scriptblocks to the various GUI events. Click on your button and find the OnClick event and double click in the text field to add the code template. When you copy the generated code you will see a script block created for your button. You can launch your script from there. You'll need to access the forms properties to get the data the user entered. Something like `& .\MyScript -Param1 $form1.textbox1.text -Param2 $form1.textbox2.text`.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy. After some fiddling I ended up with `Start-Process powershell.exe -argumentlist "e:\temp\test.ps1","-sizelimit 0","-listtype pinglist"` which works. A bit different than your code but definetely your credit:)